# GRUB2 other input methods?

Tags: grub2, input-method

I use a Logitech G510 keyboard which does not work during boot until the SO (whatever it is) is loaded. This weren't a problem because I only need from time to time to enter de BIOS, and in that case I plug another simpler keyboard. But now that I need to choose the entry boot every time I turn on the computer, so I need another input method to chose an option.

**In GRUB2, Is there any other input method (mouse, bootable USB, etc.) to chose the entry boot?**

Related:

- Ubuntu 13.04, Raring Ringtail
- GRUB version: grub-install (GRUB) 2.00-13ubuntu3
- BIOS Legacy USB Keyboard Support is enabled

*Attempt 1*:

- Installed BURG with default configurations -> Keyboard does not work
- Configuring BURG with GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=usb_keyboard -> Causes reboot
- Adding "insmod usb" & "insmod usb_keyboard" -> Causes reboot

EDIT: Attempt 1 and BIOS checking.

Comment: This is not possible without mod your kernel. Jernelmodding means a lot of work and is not worth it

Comment: May be you could use the burg bootloader instead.  Try this with your keyboard and report the success.

Comment: Thanks @Josh: I installed BURG but it does the same.